# Aws free tier pricing for Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

On the [AWS site](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/), it's stated that Lambda's free tier features 1,000,000 requests per month. Is it 1 mil requests spread across all Lambda functions in my AWS account, or is it 1 mil requests per 1 Lambda function? Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's 1 million requests per month **per account.** Quoting the [AWS Lambda pricing](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/pricing/) page (same page you linked):

> **Lambda pricing details**
>
> Lambda counts a request each time it starts executing in response to an event notification or invoke call, including test invokes from the console. **You are charged for the total number of requests across all your functions.**